# How I can split a sentence containing values into columns with its value in python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I need to convert this string into rooms and their specific value with the help of python code. I tried with

```
df1[['Master Bedroom', 'bedroom','bedroom','bedroom','study room']] = df['Area(sq.ft)'].str.split(',',1, expand=True)
```

but unfortunately its saying

```
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

Below is the input:

```
0 | Area(sq.ft)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1 | Master Bedroom, 181, Bedroom, 153.08, Bedroom, 143, Bedroom, 132, 
  | Study Room, 72.75
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
2 | Master Bedroom, 144.83, Bedroom, 126.88, Bedroom, 142.62
```

Below is the output:

```
| Master Bedroom |  Bedroom |  Bedroom |  Bedroom | Study Room
----------------------------------------------------------------
| 181            |  153.08  |  143     |  132     | 72.75
| 144.83         |  126.88  |  142.62  |  0       | 0
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your sample input and expected output as text in the body of your question, not as an image or external link, to make a [mcve]. See [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: You may need to use `apply()` to convert every text into `pd.Series` and then you can use `join()` and it will add `NaN` in missing places - and you can fill `NaN` with `0` - `.fillna(0)`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that `split(',', 1,...)` with parameter `1` gives only 2 columns.

But other problem is that `split(',')` gives list with 10 elements

```
["Master Bedroom", "181", "Bedroom", "153.08", "Bedroom", "143", "Bedroom", "132", "Study Room", "72.75"]
```

but you need only 5 elements

```
["181", "153.08", "143", "132", "72.75"]
```

You could create

```
df1[['name1', 'Master Bedroom', 'name2', 'Bedroom', 'name3', 'Bedroom', 'name4', 'Bedroom', 'name5', 'Study Room']] = ...
```

and later drop columns `nameX` but it may put values in wrong places if you have less `Bedrooms`.

---

You could use `.apply(function)` to run more complex function which splits text and creates `Series` with `result[name] = value`. And this will create only 5 columns and it will automatically add `NaN` in empty places. But later you can put `0` using `.fillna(0)`

But there is other problem - you have 3 columns with the same name `Bedroom` and it makes problem to create `Series` with 3 values (like in dictionary you can have many keys with the same name).

I would add numbers to names to create columns `Bedroom 1`, `Bedroom 2`, `Bedroom 3`,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
'Area(sq.ft)': [
'Master Bedroom, 181, Bedroom, 153.08, Bedroom, 143, Bedroom, 132, Study Room, 72.75', 
'Master Bedroom, 144.83, Bedroom, 126.88, Bedroom, 142.62',
]
})

#print(df)

def convert(text):
    
    result = pd.Series(dtype=object)

    items = text.split(', ')
    
    all_names  = items[0::2]
    all_values = items[1::2]
    
    number = 1
    
    for name, value in zip(all_names, all_values):
        if name == 'Bedroom':
            name = f'{name} {number}'
            number += 1
    
        result[name] = value
    
    return result

new_df = df['Area(sq.ft)'].apply(convert)
new_df = new_df.fillna(0)

print(new_df)
```

Result:

```
  Master Bedroom Bedroom 1 Bedroom 2 Bedroom 3 Study Room
0            181    153.08       143       132      72.75
1         144.83    126.88    142.62         0          0
```